# Power BI Aggregations - Detail Tables Must Be DirectQuery Tables?

Tags: powerbi

I have a simple data model, from the Contoso database, that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to set up the table named Online Sales Aggregate as an aggregate table. When I attempt to set up a mapping, all the detail tables are disabled (see below) 
[image]

When I hover over a table I see a message that says, ***"Customers (for example) must be a DirectQuery table to be used as the detail table."***

All the tables in the model, including the Online Sales Aggregate table were imported. Why do the detail tables need to be DQ tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a limitation that Microsoft has imposed at least while aggregates are still in preview.

From Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-aggregations#validations):

> Detail table must be DirectQuery, not Import.

---

According to Microsoft people, it's likely that this limitation will eventually go away.

> **v-lili6-msft**: [Power bi product team is improving this preview feature](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Aggregations-doesn-t-appear-to-work-for-detail-table-which-is/td-p/634429)
>
> **JoshCaplan-MSFT**: [This is still a work in progress but it is coming.](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/aggregations-for-petabyte-scale-bi-is-generally-available/)

---

To expand on what David says below, I'd guess that removing this limitation is not a high priority since the main use case for aggregations is for datasets that are too unwieldy to import. If you've already imported all the data, then adding an aggregate table probably won't really speed things up that much in most cases.

If you still do need an aggregate table for an imported table, then you can do the workaround he describes by creating a summarized table via the query editor or a DAX calculated table and write your measure(s) to try to read from that first. An added bonus with this method is that you can use custom measures in your summarized table instead of being limited to aggregate summarization functions (Count, GroupBy, Max, Min, Sum), though you'll need to be careful with how you handle non-additive measures.

Comment: Thank you Alexis. I saw the documentation you referenced, but I assumed, incorrectly, that Aggregations was now GA and this limitation was lifted because the documentation was from 18 months ago.

Comment: Note that using Aggregations _without_ DirectQuery is unusual, as calculations on imported detail tables are typically fast enough.  Also you can always write a measure that reads from the aggregation table and use it in certian reports.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Thanks for the response, but it doesn't make a great deal of sense to me. To use aggregation tables I'm supposed to now convert all my imported tables to DQ tables? Doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose of imported tables, and the DAX power and flexibility achieved with such tables? And, what if some of my imported tables didn't come from a database that can be connected to on demand, or didn't come from a traditional database at all? OTOH, your suggestion about creating measures that read from the aggregation table would work.

Comment: It’s just that you shouldn’t normally _need_ aggregations for In Memory tables: they are typically fast enough already.  The feature was really designed to help with scenarios where there are too many rows to Import.  Aggregations over In Memory tables is a totally valid scenario for very large models.  It just hasn’t been implemented yet.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Thanks David. I understand your point. However, I would argue with your statement that people often use DirectQuery tables because there are too many rows to import. I think the most common use case for DQ tables is the need for near real-time views of their data. In any case, thanks for your comments.